# unityでバイオハザードのようなカットシーンを作りたいのですがシーンの切り替えについて質問します。

Tags: unity3d

unity初心者です。
ゲーム中の例えばボス戦前などに、イベントとしてカットシーンを入れたいと思っています。
登場人物のアニメーションやリップシンクなどは、外部ツールで作成済みです。

unityにインポート後に、舞台（背景などを）を設置して、そこで演技をさせたいのですが、
色々調べてもカメラワークの切り替え方法などはCinema Directorなどの有料アセットでどうにか
なりそうですが、肝心のカットシーンの組み込み方法がわからなかったので質問します。

特定の場所にプレイヤーが到着→カットシーンがスタート→終了後に自動的にボス戦や別の場面へ切り替え。
が、必要です。
よろしくお願い致します。。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/53806

Answer (score 1):

Cinema Directorは、シーン実行時の挙動を設定出来ます。

Unityエディターを再生して、ゲームを開始する時にシーンを再生する(On Start)のと、トリガーを設置して、何かしらのオブジェクト（コライダー）が、そのトリガーに触れるとシーンが再生されるパターン(On Trigger)。

自分も始めたばかりで詳しくはないのですが、投稿者様のやりたいことは、多分プレイヤーがある部屋に入ったらシーンが再生されるということだと思うので、
それだったら、例えば部屋の中にカットシーントリガーを配置し、プレイヤーをターゲットトリガーに設定し、そのプレイヤーがカットシーントリガーのコライダに触れたらシーン再生という流れで良いでのはないでしょうか。